# Чи є в українській мові відповідник до слова "бар"?

Tags: відповідник

Слово "бар" походить від англійського "bar", та має таке [значення](http://sum.in.ua/s/bar):

> Невеликий ресторан, в якому напої і закуски споживають біля стойки
>   буфету або за столиками.

Цікаво чи є влучний відповідник до цього запозиченого слова. На Словотворі я не знайшов потрібної інформації. Слова "корчма" чи "шинок" не підходять, бо згідно до [СУМу](http://sum.in.ua/s/shynok) - це:

> Невеликий заклад, де продавалися на розлив спиртні напої

Тобто, я так розумію, в даних закладах акцент робився саме на продажу алкогольних напоїв.

Ще одна трудність полягає у тому, що навіть якщо ми замінимо "бар" цими словами, то як бути із такими варіантами як: "суші-бар", "винний бар", "молочний бар" тощо?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Коли трудність з тим, шчо лише до спиртне чи не можна пристосувати не спиртне, то новішиј СУМ не такиј суровиј.

> [КО́РЧМА́, ко́рчми́, *діал.* КО́РШМА́, ко́ршми́, *ж.*](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=44376&page=1405)
>
> 1. *іст.* Шинок, заїзд, де продавалися спиртні напої.
> 2. Сучасний ресторан, стилізований під такий заклад.

Нове ([не зовсім](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%87%D0%BC%D0%B0#%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81) — оскільки ранїше було виду кавјарнї) означінє не лиш усуває спиртневиј напрям, а сам спиртневиј напрям перетворює на «історичне». Тобто з цӧго погляду проблем ніяких. Гадаю, шчо питанє тут: ж бо корчма — загальніше понятє, де стіјка — *bar*, не завше є основою, себто навіть можлива незвичаєва відсутність [*шинквасу*](http://sum.in.ua/s/shynkvas).

А *шинок* шче не ввіјшов в новішиј словник через недонаповність, однак, походить від нїмецького [*Schenke*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Schenke). Тому ось шче довід складностӥ ӧго називати украӥнським відповідником, хоча слово добре і давно прижило ся.

Answer (score 2):

У мене бар асоціюється здебільшого з місцем куди люди ходять на пиво. Отже,

> **[ПИВНИ́ЦЯ](http://sum.in.ua/s/pyvnycja)**, і, *жін*.
>
> **1.** Заклад, де продають і п'ють пиво. *Хіба не з ним інколи заходили вони в .. пивницю випити по склянці пива й поговорити щиро,
>   по-товариському?* (Анатолій Шиян, Магістраль, 1934, 168); *Ми.. За
>   сосновим столом сидимо У маленькій, дорожній пивниці* (Платон Воронько,
>   Мирний неспокій, 1960, 142).